# Full screen background image only full screen when browser window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, fullscreen

The background image for this only "pops" into place as a full screen image after the browser window is resized. This seems to happen only in firefox and opera but is ok in safari. Not tested in IE yet. How can I make it instantly full screen when the page loads instead? Note when displayDiv div is removed it works fine. Thanks

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/UggMq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger the resize event when the page loads:

```
$(window).trigger("resize");
```

Fixed fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/UggMq/1/